# Https to Http rule rewrite Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to redirect all https traffic to http after removing an SSL certificate but the rule doesn't appear to be working. I have lifted the following rule from previous examples, but in every case it is still pointing to the https version. Any ideas what is going wrong?

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS to HTTP" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

If I enter https://www.example.com it doesn't redirect. It tries to hit that actual site. 
Many thanks

Comment: If you have no certificate, how will anyone get to your SSL site to be redirected at all? Don't remove SSL, in fact, go the other way and make everything secure - you can do it for free these days!

Answer (score 1):

@DavidG in comments was right. Also your rule has small mistake in condition. Instead

```
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
```

You should have

```
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks, the reason I'd like to "remove" the SSL is that I am downgrading from Basic to Shared Web Site and SSL is not available on the latter.